# Eclipse is not showing any projects from my workspace folder even the projects are there?

Tags: eclipse

We are using subclips as a SVN client for our Eclipse and I have successfully checked-out the list of projects to 'C:\workspace\myprojects' folder then I have opened the eclipse and given the workspace location as 'C:\workspace\myprojects' but it's not showing any projects even there are projects, Why?

So I have imported all the projects one by one through the eclipse feature and now i can able  to see the projects but my question why should i need to import even i have given the eclipse workspace folder as 'C:\workspace\myprojects'?

NOTE: But the sampe scenario is working fine in others machine, i.e they no need to import all the projects one by one when they have given the Eclipse workspace folder as 'C:\workspace\myprojects'.

Regards,
Baji

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse uses the metadata to determine which projects are in the workspace. So you have to import the projects into the workspace even though they already reside in the same directory in the filesystem. Just call File / Import / Existing Projects from the filesystem and select the projects that are already there. It's a pain, but it works.

Comment: yes! but it's working fine in other machines even they not imported. how?

Comment: I don't know. It may be that Eclipse had never opened the workspace folder before the projects were checked out there, or it may be the opposite. Experiment a bit and see if that affects how Eclipse behaves.

Comment: it might be :) 

Any how by importing manually i can able to do my work.

Thank you very much for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have a project inside the workspace directory doesn't mean Eclipse opens it or even sees it automatically. You must use File - Import - General - Import existing project into workspace to have your project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Actually some of eclipse configuration file was deleted. hence it was not able to show.

finally after reverting the it I can able to see all the projects.